# Everything inside my canvas got bigger after canvas resize

Tags: javascript, canvas, resize

When I first started this project that I'm working on, my canvas size with 1400px wide and 480px tall. I realized that I am going to need to make the canvas the same size as the window itself later, so I did that and everything inside of the canvas zoomed in or something. I set a `drawImage();` to be 300 px wide and 180 px tall, and it is a LOT bigger than that, the image is actually the same width as the canvas now. Any suggestions? Here's the link to the project:

http://brycemckenney.com/animation-app

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the dimensions through css, instead of the physical dimensions of the (image) canvas.

The relevant piece (for others to read in the future) of your code is:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
$(canvas).css({
    height: windowHeight - 8,
    width: windowWidth - 8
});
```

Think of it like this: suppose you have a normal jpg-image.
That jpg has it's own 'physical' dimensions (aka width and height).
In *both* HTML *and* CSS you can set the dimensions (in px, percent, etc) that you'd like the browser to render (scale) the picture (hey, the picture already has a immutable size right?).

Now for canvas:
In order for canvas to have a physical width/height, you have to set the `.width` and `.height` of the canvas-element itself, either in HTML or per javascript (a side-effect is that setting the physical dimensions is that the canvas will clear itself, as per spec).
Then to *scale* the image (like you did with the above jpg example) you use css (again in px/percent/etc).
I think this is a clever solution by the way to add that new canvas-element to the HTML-Spec!

So, rounding up:
A canvas with a width and a height of 300 px rendered as 100% of a container (like document.body) that measures 900x900px will be scaled-up 3 times!
The reverse (scaling down) will let you draw even more crisp lines by the way!

Hope this helps your understanding!

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! I just added `canvas.width = windowWidth - 8;` and the same for height, and it worked. Thanks!